# Error en laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Estoy tratando de pasar a la vista el nombre y el id de las categorías de los productos y me esta generando el siguiente error.

> "Trying to get property 'category_id' of non-object (View: C:\Users\RaFaE\blog\resources\views\admin\article\create.blade.php)"

Anexo códigos:

Controlador

```
public function create()
{
  $categories = category::orderBy('id_category')->Pluck('name_cat','id_category');
    //dd($categories);
      return view('admin.article.create',compact('categories'));
}
```

Vista

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
      {{$category->name_cat}}
      @endforeach
```

Modelo article

```
public function category(){  return $this->belongsTo('App\category', 'category_id');}
```

Modelo category

```
  public function articles(){

  return $this->hasMany('App\article');
}
```

Al usar DD me devuelve la coleccion con el nombre y el id de las 14 categorias

```
Collection {#563 ▼ #items: array:14 [▶]}
```

Nota: Si pongo cualquier texto dentro del foreach hace el recorrido completo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
  {{$category->name_cat}}
  @endforeach
```

Prueba con esto

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
  {{$category['name_cat']}}
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Estoy tratando de usar esos valores en un select, el problema es que al parecer solamente me esta mandando a la vista el primer valor del $categories = category::orderBy('id_category')->Pluck('name_cat','id_category'); si lo colo de esta forma al hacer la insercion de los datos el valor que esta pasando es el name de la categoria, si los invierto y pongo id_category de primero, hace la insercion de los datos correctamente, pero en el select solamente se ve el id de la categoria y no el nombre

Comment: Prueba con esto                                                                            
$categories = category::orderBy('id_category', asc)->Pluck('name_cat','id_category')->get();

Comment: Si le agrego el get(); me genera el siguiente error ( Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in C:\Users\RaFaE\blog\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\ArticleController.php )

Comment: Este te deberia servir                                                                         
$categories = category::select('name_cat', 'id_category')->orderBy('id_category', 'asc')->get();

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por estar al pendiente amigo este ultimo codigo si me sirvio eres un crack , podrias explicarme cual es la diferencia o el por que con el select si funciono?

Comment: Con mucho gusto. No sabria exactamente pero creo que la razón es porque pluck se utiliza para traer solo un campo unicamente, no varios.